# Fetching JSON data and displaying it in ListView React Native

Tags: json, listview, react-native, ios7

I am trying to read json data from https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users in the React Native framework into a ListView.

Below is the JSON data which I am trying to use.

```
 [
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Leanne Graham",
    "username": "Bret",
    "email": "Sincere@april.biz",
    "address": {
      "street": "Kulas Light",
      "suite": "Apt. 556",
      "city": "Gwenborough",
      "zipcode": "92998-3874",
      "geo": {
        "lat": "-37.3159",
        "lng": "81.1496"
      }
    },
    "phone": "1-770-736-8031 x56442",
    "website": "hildegard.org",
    "company": {
      "name": "Romaguera-Crona",
      "catchPhrase": "Multi-layered client-server neural-net",
      "bs": "harness real-time e-markets"
    }
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Ervin Howell",
    "username": "Antonette",
    "email": "Shanna@melissa.tv",
    "address": {
      "street": "Victor Plains",
      "suite": "Suite 879",
      "city": "Wisokyburgh",
      "zipcode": "90566-7771",
      "geo": {
        "lat": "-43.9509",
        "lng": "-34.4618"
      }
    },
    "phone": "010-692-6593 x09125",
    "website": "anastasia.net",
    "company": {
      "name": "Deckow-Crist",
      "catchPhrase": "Proactive didactic contingency",
      "bs": "synergize scalable supply-chains"
    }
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "name": "Clementine Bauch",
    "username": "Samantha",
    "email": "Nathan@yesenia.net",
    "address": {
      "street": "Douglas Extension",
      "suite": "Suite 847",
      "city": "McKenziehaven",
      "zipcode": "59590-4157",
      "geo": {
        "lat": "-68.6102",
        "lng": "-47.0653"
      }
    },
    "phone": "1-463-123-4447",
    "website": "ramiro.info",
    "company": {
      "name": "Romaguera-Jacobson",
      "catchPhrase": "Face to face bifurcated interface",
      "bs": "e-enable strategic applications"
    }
  },
  {
    "id": 4,
    "name": "Patricia Lebsack",
    "username": "Karianne",
    "email": "Julianne.OConner@kory.org",
    "address": {
      "street": "Hoeger Mall",
      "suite": "Apt. 692",
      "city": "South Elvis",
      "zipcode": "53919-4257",
      "geo": {
        "lat": "29.4572",
        "lng": "-164.2990"
      }
    },
    "phone": "493-170-9623 x156",
    "website": "kale.biz",
    "company": {
      "name": "Robel-Corkery",
      "catchPhrase": "Multi-tiered zero tolerance productivity",
      "bs": "transition cutting-edge web services"
    }
  },
  {
    "id": 5,
    "name": "Chelsey Dietrich",
    "username": "Kamren",
    "email": "Lucio_Hettinger@annie.ca",
    "address": {
      "street": "Skiles Walks",
      "suite": "Suite 351",
      "city": "Roscoeview",
      "zipcode": "33263",
      "geo": {
        "lat": "-31.8129",
        "lng": "62.5342"
      }
    },
    "phone": "(254)954-1289",
    "website": "demarco.info",
    "company": {
      "name": "Keebler LLC",
      "catchPhrase": "User-centric fault-tolerant solution",
      "bs": "revolutionize end-to-end systems"
    }
  },
  {
    "id": 6,
    "name": "Mrs. Dennis Schulist",
    "username": "Leopoldo_Corkery",
    "email": "Karley_Dach@jasper.info",
    "address": {
      "street": "Norberto Crossing",
      "suite": "Apt. 950",
      "city": "South Christy",
      "zipcode": "23505-1337",
      "geo": {
        "lat": "-71.4197",
        "lng": "71.7478"
      }
    },
    "phone": "1-477-935-8478 x6430",
    "website": "ola.org",
    "company": {
      "name": "Considine-Lockman",
      "catchPhrase": "Synchronised bottom-line interface",
      "bs": "e-enable innovative applications"
    }
  },
  {
    "id": 7,
    "name": "Kurtis Weissnat",
    "username": "Elwyn.Skiles",
    "email": "Telly.Hoeger@billy.biz",
    "address": {
      "street": "Rex Trail",
      "suite": "Suite 280",
      "city": "Howemouth",
      "zipcode": "58804-1099",
      "geo": {
        "lat": "24.8918",
        "lng": "21.8984"
      }
    },
    "phone": "210.067.6132",
    "website": "elvis.io",
    "company": {
      "name": "Johns Group",
      "catchPhrase": "Configurable multimedia task-force",
      "bs": "generate enterprise e-tailers"
    }
  },
  {
    "id": 8,
    "name": "Nicholas Runolfsdottir V",
    "username": "Maxime_Nienow",
    "email": "Sherwood@rosamond.me",
    "address": {
      "street": "Ellsworth Summit",
      "suite": "Suite 729",
      "city": "Aliyaview",
      "zipcode": "45169",
      "geo": {
        "lat": "-14.3990",
        "lng": "-120.7677"
      }
    },
    "phone": "586.493.6943 x140",
    "website": "jacynthe.com",
    "company": {
      "name": "Abernathy Group",
      "catchPhrase": "Implemented secondary concept",
      "bs": "e-enable extensible e-tailers"
    }
  },
  {
    "id": 9,
    "name": "Glenna Reichert",
    "username": "Delphine",
    "email": "Chaim_McDermott@dana.io",
    "address": {
      "street": "Dayna Park",
      "suite": "Suite 449",
      "city": "Bartholomebury",
      "zipcode": "76495-3109",
      "geo": {
        "lat": "24.6463",
        "lng": "-168.8889"
      }
    },
    "phone": "(775)976-6794 x41206",
    "website": "conrad.com",
    "company": {
      "name": "Yost and Sons",
      "catchPhrase": "Switchable contextually-based project",
      "bs": "aggregate real-time technologies"
    }
  },
  {
    "id": 10,
    "name": "Clementina DuBuque",
    "username": "Moriah.Stanton",
    "email": "Rey.Padberg@karina.biz",
    "address": {
      "street": "Kattie Turnpike",
      "suite": "Suite 198",
      "city": "Lebsackbury",
      "zipcode": "31428-2261",
      "geo": {
        "lat": "-38.2386",
        "lng": "57.2232"
      }
    },
    "phone": "024-648-3804",
    "website": "ambrose.net",
    "company": {
      "name": "Hoeger LLC",
      "catchPhrase": "Centralized empowering task-force",
      "bs": "target end-to-end models"
    }
  }
]
```

The fetch call takes place in the following method which then sets the data source.

```
componentDidMount() {
return fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users')
 .then((response) => response.json())
 .then((responseJson) => {
   this.setState({
     isLoading: false,
     dataSource: 
     this.state.dataSource.cloneWithRows(responseJson.name)
   }, function() {
     // do something with new state
     console.log(responseJson);
   });
 })
 .catch((error) => {
   console.error(error);
 });
```

}

At this point being new to the React Native framework I am struggling to read this data into the List View.

Within the Render Method I have this code which I would expect to 
then display the ListView.

```
<View>
<Image source={require('./Resources/house.png')} style=
{styles.image}/>
  {spinner}
  <Text style = { styles.description }>{this.state.message}</Text>
  <ListView
    dataSource = { this.state.dataSource}
    renderRow = { this.renderRow.bind(this)}
    />
</View>
```

However I am getting ListView is not defined. I have checked various forum posts but I cannot seem to find the solution.

Any ideas?

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, if `ListView` in undefined, check that you have imported it from the `react-native` package at the top of the file:

```
import { ListView } from 'react-native';
```

Additionally `responseJson` variable is an array of items, but you are trying to access the `.name` property on it as if it were just a single item. If you want to pluck just the name property of each list item, you can do the following:

```
this.state.dataSource.cloneWithRows(responseJson.map(item => item.name))
```

Further, the React Native `ListView` component is now deprecated, as mentioned in the ListView docs:

> DEPRECATED - use one of the new list components, such as FlatList or SectionList for bounded memory use, fewer bugs, better performance, an easier to use API, and more features. Check out this blog post for more details.

See [this blog post](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/blog/2017/03/13/better-list-views.html) for further details.